# C# HtmlEncode, then Javascript insert using .innerHTML

Tags: c#, javascript, html

What follows is a piece of text that gets HtmlEncoded in C# before being sent to the browser (during a callback). Once received, in Javascript I do `myDiv.innerHTML = theStringBelow`;

```
<span xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
      xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls"
      xmlns:ext="my_namespace:my_xslt_extension">Some text to be shown.</span>
```

However, what results is that I simply see the exact text shown above. It isn't being treated as an html element that got added to the DOM, but as plain text. When I add the exact same text through javascript (e.g., I skip the callback, and just say `myDiv="exactString`") it DOES get added correctly (it gets treated as a span).

What is going on? Do I have to un-encode it? Should I not have encoded to begin with?

**Edit**
The question still stands for curiosity's sake, but I have fixed the issue simply by not HtmlEncoding the data. An earlier issue must have added onto this one, making me think the HtmlEncoding was still necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `HTMLEncode` it if it is to become HTML nodes. What HTML encoding will do is turn your string from above into this:

```
&lt;span xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
  xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls"
  xmlns:ext="my_namespace:my_xslt_extension"&gt;Some text to be shown.&lt;/span&gt;
```

Try passing the string in as it is. You will of course have to escape the string. But once it has become a string in JavaScript it should be unescaped as it is being made into a string in memory. Then you should be able to do the `div.innerHTML` call and get your expected result. The escaping of the string can probably be accomplished by doing the following:

```
// in your .cs code-behind/view/whatever.
string = string.replace("""", "\""");
```

Which should produce:

```
<span xmlns:asp=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20\" 
  xmlns:SharePoint=\"Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls\"
  xmlns:ext=\"my_namespace:my_xslt_extension\">Some text to be shown.</span>
```

Which you can then output like so:

```
// in your webform/view
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mystring;
  mystring = "<%=string;%>";
</script>
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: When I use the span I had above, everything works fine. However, when I have real data I get an error saying "unterminated string constant". Does that essentially mean I had a badly formed string on the server side that I then dumped down to the client? Or do I need to somehow escape the string on the server first? .. btw, like I said, the example I gave, works fine and its being sent from the server. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: If your data is already escaped, then I could see this error occurring when you try to escape it again. But without seeing your actual implementation I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Also, @KyleM I would need to know what system was producing that error. Is that a JavaScript error or a C# compiler error?

Answer (score 0):

HTML Encode will turn `<` into `&lt;` and so on. This breaks HTML Formatting and is used so blocks of text like this:

```
Insert <name> here
```

Does not turn out like this:

```
Insert  here
```

If your intent is to have the `<span ...` get inserted into the html directly you either need to NOT encode it on the way out, or if that will disrupt transmission, you need to decode it in js before you set the `.innerHTML` part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that is informative. Though you did not mention *how* to decode it in js.. still, I've marked it as the answer since I at least have confirmation I'm not crazy.

Comment: @KyleM: Updated with a link to the function in javascript.

Comment: The update is incorrect; `unescape` is for URL decoding, not HTML decoding.  There is no native JavaScript function for encoding or decoding HTML-encoded strings.

Comment: See my answer, the HTML does not need to be decoded. The string just needs to be escaped before providing it as a JavaScript string. (Most likely)

Comment: @Jacob: You are totally right. I did a quick search and didn't read fully. As I stated in my answer, you do not need to encode it on the way out unless it's interfering with your transfer medium (XML without CDATA for example).